# Auditing PowerShell Activity

Tags: sharepoint-online, powershell, office-365, security

I can see changes made to SharePoint Online using the available audit logs etc. But I don't see PowerShell activity by admins or others. Most like a person who is going to hack the platform is going to use PowerShell.

How can we view/monitor changes or activity made using PowerShell in o365 & SharePoint online?

Comment: If you're concerned about attacks using stolen credentials, I would suggest you start in Azure AD since that is where the authentication process takes place. Once they've gotten to SPO, they've gotten too far. Read up on protecting credentials in AAD, such as MFA enforcement, disabling non-compliant devices from accessing services, etc.

Comment: Yes. But also wondering about the PowerShell angle?

Comment: How is PoSh different? It goes through the same auth mechanisms that users go through using the user's credential, provided you're not using CID/Cert/Secret.

Comment: @TrevorSeward that's exactly my question. Why would changes made using PowerShell not be audited? If they are, then I need to figure out why they aren't appearing in my logs. So that's my question.

Comment: Now SharePoint can’t monitor changes or activity made by using PowerShell in Microsoft O365 and SharePoint online.

The only is to make your suggestion in the User Voice.https://sharepoint.uservoice.com/

Comment: PowerShell activity is audited to the extent that activity in the web for those same actions would be audited (i.e. adding a user to a SharePoint group).